# Generic function to read from a `.json` file

Tags: f#, json.net

So, I can easily write an arbitrary type to `JSON` with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
type X = {
Number: decimal
Sequence: decimal
NumList: decimal list
}

let createItem (n, s, nL) = 
    {Number = n; 
    Sequence = s; 
    NumList = nL}

let items =
    [
        (1M, 1M, [1M; 2M; 3M])
        (2M, 2M, [2M; 4M; 6M])
        (3M, 3M, [3M; 6M; 9M])
    ]
    |> List.map createItem

open Newtonsoft.Json
open System.IO

let writeToJson (path: string) (obj: 'a) : unit =
    let serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)

    File.WriteAllText(path, serialized)

writeToJson "xList.json" items
```

How can I write a function generic enough that I can read a `JSON` file?  In other words, I'd like something like:

```
let readFromJson (path: string) (t: 'T) = 
    let convertToQr = File.ReadAllText(path)

    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t list>(convertToQr)
```

where the second argument is the `Type` of the object in `path`, but I don't know how to do that.  If I try to use this function as is, I get a compiler error.

How can I declare in the second argument above the type of the thing that is in `path`?  Can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic parameters, when explicitly defined, are written in angle brackets immediately after function name, before regular parameters:

```
let readFromJson<'T>(path: string) =
   let convertToQr = File.ReadAllText(path) 

   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T list>(convertToQr)
```

Usage:

```
readFromJson<string> "/some/file.json"
```

Alternatively, you can specify the return type of your function, and let the compiler infer all generic parameters and arguments for you:

```
let readFromJson(path: string) : 't list =
   let convertToQr = File.ReadAllText(path) 

   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(convertToQr)
```

Here, the compiler knows that the generic argument of `DeserializeObject` must be `'t list`, because its result is being returned from `readFromJson`, and the result type of `readFromJson` is explicitly declared to be `'t list`. Similarly, just by noticing a generic type in the function definition, the compiler will infer that the function has one generic parameter.

In a similar way, you can let the compiler infer the required type when you *call* the function:

```
// call inferred to readFromJson<string>, because that's the required return type
let s: string list = readFromJson "/some/file.json"
```